# How to automate Windows remote desktop login poup in server using Web Driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Step 1: I have provided the login in browser level

Step 2: It moved to remote desktop

Step 3: When I click on remote desktop icon in browser it will show the window authentication login of QA server

Step 4: I have tried with selenium IDE to record but the actions are not recorded after the click on remote desktop

Here selenium was installed in my pc. Is it possible to automate the window authentication login of QA server using the web driver in my pc or should I install it in server too.

If yes, could any one provide the solution for above issue.

Comment: Hi Bala and welcome to sqa.  Is the remote desktop session inside the browser?  Is there anything extra there?  You may need to think outside of just selenium.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that Selenium is right here.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Lyndon - this may require additional tooling beyond Selenium.  If you are on a Windows OS, I have had good experiences with AutoIt for scripting system interactions like this.  You can find more details about this tool at:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/